# Applying fine-grained security to an existing application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I've inherited a reasonably large and complex ASP.NET MVC3 web application using EF Code First on SQL Server. It uses ASP.NET Membership roles with database authentication. The controller actions are secured with attributes derived from AuthorizeAttribute that map roles to actions. There are extension methods for the finer points, such as showing a particular widget to particular roles. This is works great and I have a good understanding of the current security model.

I've been asked to provide finer grained security at the data level. For example a 'Customer' user can only see data (throughout the database) associated with themselves and not other Customers. The problem is that 'Customer' is only 1 of 5 different types with their own specific restrictions (each of the 9 roles is one of these 5 types).

The best thing I can think of is to go through all the data repositories and extend each and every LINQ statements/query with a filter for every user type. Even if I had time for that it doesn't seem like the most elegant way.

Any suggestions? I really don't know where to start with this so anything could be helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: That's a good way to start, but it will get more complicated if you need to have super users who could see other people's data. Hopefully all queries are done through some sort of service layer. Then it would be easy to put in security at any level of complexity. Don't forget to secure the updates too. (User A can't modify User B's data.)

Answer (score 0):

Data driven security must be performed in queries. Adding this in the latter stage of the project is really time consuming. Not due to programming but due to testing. If the management has this requirement they must simply accept that.

You can start with refactoring some base queries. Every query must access some `DbSet` so instead of accessing the `DbSet` access some helper method applying the security on that set. You can play with `DbSet`s exposed on your derived context or you can even try to derive your own `DbSet`s and re-implement `IQueryalbe.Expression` (explicitly implement) to add your filtering logic directly to the set.

The real complications began in lazy and eager loading. EF doesn't provide way to filter lazily or eagerly loaded data. With well designed aggregates you should not need cross customer lazy loading and eager loading. If you need it you will have to refactor that part of code to make it work properly (it will not be only about adding some condition to a query).